# WSO2 AS: get Axis2 MessageContext in CXF?

Tags: rest, cxf, apache-axis, jax-rs, wso2

I deploy JAX-RS service to CXF (WSO2 AS 5.1.0) as WAR-file.
Also I have Axis2 [Handler](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/engine/Handler.html) deployed as module (MAR) which used to modify Axis2 [MessageContext](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/context/MessageContext.html) in IN/OUT flows.
How can I get Axis2 MessageContext from JAX-RS service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. By design we don't allow to access Axis2 MessageContext from tomcat container where the JAX-RS service is running.